# How to get the 'rating' of an artist?

Tags: audio, media, mediamonkey

I'm using MediaMonkey, and I'm looking for some way to get "the rating" of every artist in the library, something like the average rating of the songs of that artist. So I know the best artists and buy more albums by them.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: every artist in *your* library, or in *mediamonkey's* library?  and where do you want ratings from... *your* library or *theirs*?

Comment: Everything in my library is already organized in my MediaMonkey. I want to get the ratings of the artists from my library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several steps are needed:

1. register at [Last.fm](http://last.fm/) or a similar service suggesting music you may like
2. install [lastfm scrobbler plugin for mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Last.FM_Scrobbler_Plugin_Info), for it to submit music you listen to your last.fm profile
3. Visit your last.fm profile from time to time, to get: a) statistics of what are your favorite Artists, Albums and Tracks, b) suggestions of other Albums and Tracks - both by your favorite Artists, and by other Artists.

In addition to telling you what you like listening a lot, Last.fm also has features to "love" specific tracks - to tune music suggestions. Also, you can literally "blacklist" some compositions, to further tune music suggestions to your liking.

An extra bonus of this solution is that you can use the same approach from many computers and many different media players - lastfm plugins are available for a wide variety of media players. For example, you could setup both your work and home computers to report your music, to get the most accurate music preferences statistics.

The drawback of this solution is that it requires permanent internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's possible, but maybe with the [Magic Nodes Addon](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19168) and a SQL filter.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing I can think of would be to use Tagging. http://www.mediamonkey.com/information/free/#tag

Comment: Sorry but that's not helpful. How is this feature, which I already use of course, useful in this scenario?